# Java jeditorpane rtf images

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I would like to get a JEditorPane to display RTF images like microsoft wordpad. I have a simple program I got from an example off of the web. I created a demo file in wordpad with all of the styles wordpad supports. Strikethrough, super-script, sub-script and highlight are not being read or displayed when reading the file. Highlight would be nice other than that I don't really need the others. The part that is critical is the images in the RTF, they show in wordpad but on in java. I am using:

```
RTFEditorKit rtf = new RTFEditorKit();
JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
editor.setEditorKit(rtf);
rtf.read(fi, editor.getDocument(), 0);
```

If RTFEditorKit cannot support images is there a editor kit that can? I can't be the only person to try to get an RTF to work properly. I cannot use an HTML editor kit because I need the images to be embeded like the RTF format.

Comment: http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html that's alternative

Comment: Sorry, for the long delay, had an issue with my computer. The firewall at work here is not letting me get to that site are there other options?

Comment: I was only able to load the page through the google cache. I was able to get the jar file but there is not any kind of javadoc or any kind of instructions on how to use the actions this component works with. why doesn't oracle have a component that works?

Comment: So, is there some kind of actual example of how to use this or maybe some documentation like a javadoc or something? having a component is nice but what are the options for using this?

Comment: It appears that StanislavL is not around any more, does anyone else have any ideas as how to use a RTF doc in a JEditorPane?

Comment: I've never had this happen before, this question is approaching a month and has not received an answer. Is there something I can do to help this process?